# Graph Theory/Algorithm: Do multiple max flow imply multiple min cut?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

We know that Ford-Fulkerson Algorithm (FFA) will yield max flow and min cut solutions at the same time. My question is: if restricted to integer graph only, does the existence of multiple max flow paths imply the existence of multiple min cut paths?

My approach is that if we know that FFA can help us find different max flow paths, then we know that the different corresponding min cuts could be found. But how do we know whether FFA can find different max flow paths?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about graph theory, not computer programming. (It is easy to construct a counterexample.)

Comment: If it doesn't belong here it could be migrated.

Answer (score 3):

In this graph, we have to different integer max flows, but only one min cut:

[image]